# WPF - How to Backup / Restore LocalDB Programmatically - ClickOnce

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework, clickonce

I have an application which uses EF and LocalDB as it's database, published by ClickOnce.
it's my first time using LocalDB and I don't know how can i add a feature to my application to Backup/Restore The Database Programmatically.

My App Path Installed by ClickOnce :

```
C:\Users\Mahdi Rashidi\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\NOL11TLW.9XG\CZM702AQ.LPP\basu..tion_939730333fb6fcc8_0001.0002_fd707bbb3c97f8d3
```

and This is the location which Database files Installed :

```
C:\Users\Mahdi Rashidi\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\NOL11TLW.9XG\CZM702AQ.LPP\basu...exe_939730333fb6fcc8_0001.0002_none_8c555c3966727e7f
```

1. How Should I Backup/Restore the Database?
2. How Can I Keep Database Safe from ClickOnce further Updates?

Thanks alot :)

Comment: How about saving the data to `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\[SOMEFOLDER]`, rather than into the DB install directory? This would answer #2. For #1: Use board utils?

Comment: Thanks @Herdo, I think it's not up to saving directory, cause when i replace the .mdf file with a new one and run the application it showed content of first db instead of the new one. i was wondering if there is any  standard way to backup and restore db Programmatically while app is running?!

Comment: btw, i found the answer of my second question, the only remaining problem is the first one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I did for backup and restore of my localDb

```
public void BackupDatabase(string filePath)
    {
        using (TVend2014Entities dbEntities = new TVend2014Entities(BaseData.ConnectionString))
        {
            string backupQuery = @"BACKUP DATABASE ""{0}"" TO DISK = N'{1}'";
            backupQuery = string.Format(backupQuery, "full databsase file path like C:\tempDb.mdf", filePath);
            dbEntities.Database.SqlQuery<object>(backupQuery).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public void RestoreDatabase(string filePath)
    {
        using (TVend2014Entities dbEntities = new TVend2014Entities(BaseData.ConnectionString))
        {
            string restoreQuery = @"USE [Master]; 
                                                ALTER DATABASE ""{0}"" SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
                                                RESTORE DATABASE ""{0}"" FROM DISK='{1}' WITH REPLACE;
                                                ALTER DATABASE ""{0}"" SET MULTI_USER;";
            restoreQuery = string.Format(restoreQuery, "full db file path", filePath);
            var list = dbEntities.Database.SqlQuery<object>(restoreQuery).ToList();
            var resut = list.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks,for doing that Project I Used ClosedXML to Backup data into an Excel file and Restore them from it...., but your Code Seems to be a Nice Way to do an Backup/Restore Job. I should have use it.

Comment: It's Perfectly working for me. The advantage is you can Restore while you are on the same database. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bugger of a time getting my backup/restore to work from code in my application. I'm using LOCALDB and wanted to make sure that regardless of the state of the database or the location of the .mdf file that the backup and restore functions would work. After all - the DBMS should take care of that for you. In the end this is how I got my backup and restore functions to work:
Note: code in VB - save the ";" :)

Backup:

```
 Dim cbdfilename As String = controlPath & "\Backup\Temp\cbdb.bak"
    Dim connString As String = (server + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;")
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Backup database @DBNAME " _
    & " to Disk = @FILENAME" _
    & " with Format"
    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
    'execute backup
    Dim dbcmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBNAME", database)
    dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILENAME", cbdfilename)
    conn.Open()
    Try
        dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Backup DB failed" + ex.ToString)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

A key thing to note above is the SqlConnection.ClearAllPools() statement. Even though I was sure that all connections had been properly closed and disposed of in other parts of my app - somehow the DBMS was still showing an open thread.

And now the Restore:

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
        Dim connString As String = (server + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;")
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "Use master;" _
            & "Alter Database " & database & " Set Single_User With Rollback Immediate;" _
            & "Restore Database " & database & " From Disk = @FILENAME" _
            & " With Replace;" _
            & "Alter Database " & database & " Set Multi_User;"

        'execute restore
        Dim dbcmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILENAME", cbdfilename)
        conn.Open()
        Try
            dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Restore DB failed" + ex.ToString)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
            conn.Dispose()
        End Try
```

What was really weird in the SQL above is that I initially tried to use @Parms for the database name but the ALTER statements would not accept them. Kept kicking back with exceptions.

The biggest difference between my restore and the one from the earlier solution is that I only use the database name ie. "MyDB_TEST" and not the .mdf file name in my Alter and Restore statements.