# Programmatically load and use databases to MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have MS SQL Server 2008 and a program written in C#, using Entity Framework. Without using any third-party tools, can I:

1. Do daily backup to a file of only certain tables from the database?
2. Programmatically tell the SQL Server "here is the file with some tables, restore it to the new database A" and then connect to the database A and use the data, if needed, delete the database and load next file?

Comment: why not use SQL Server itself to do what you are asking?

Comment: I need to develop a tool which allows management to load copy of any past day and perform analysis between two databases without technical assistance.

Comment: sounds like you need to hire a qualified `DBA` and stop trying to cut corners meaning `Stop being Cheap`

Comment: Have you looked into LocalDB? [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966891/wpf-how-to-backup-restore-localdb-programmatically-clickonce) might be of value for doing backup and restore using LocalDB.

Comment: Thank you, dotNET. The post you pointed to is interesting and might be what I am looking for. I think if the db user has enough permissions (create, delete databases) what they show in the post should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could. The daily backup should be done by SQL then you program would be used to locate the backup and restore it to a NEW DB. You can do the backup outside of SQL but not sure why you would need/want to.

Steps would be 
- create new empty DB
- restore backup to new empty DB
- fix user permissions on DB (if applicable)

You can overload the constructor of you EF model to take in a connection string that you would make on the fly based on the DB you just reloaded.

As far as ony backing up and restoring some tables you may want to try the following.

1. Create seperate DB for the "data heavy" items that you do not need to backup and restore as often or that have no value for this process.
2. Move these items from the current DB to the New DB
3. Add views in the original DB that have the same exact name as the tables that moved out and pull in a views of the new tables on the second DB

As long as the views are names 100% the same name as the tables that you moved and the view is ONLY on the single table your program should not know the difference but you would now be able to backup the smaller DB and not include all the file and image data. Hope this makes sense

Can try to provide more info if you have a more pointed question

Comment: I know there is no problem with full backup of the database and this can be set up as a task in the Server Management (in fact this is already done). But, the current database is 500 GB, mostly because it is filled with image data. I do not need that image data in my daily backups. Is it possible in SQL Server 2008 to backup only certain tables?

Comment: I see what you are saying but the project is very big, so splitting the database and creating views seems like much work. In fact I need to backup less than 1% of the data. I am just trying to find the answer to: database has table A, table B and table C. Can I backup database to file with only table A? If this is not possible, I will serialize the entity objects to XML and keep the backups in my own format. I just want to make sure I am not reinventing the wheel since I am not expert in the SQL Server.

Comment: @Evgeny, i do not believe there is a way to backup a single table the way you are speaking of. I understand what you mean by a lot of work but in my experience when dealing with DB like this you will thank yourself time and time again for doing that work sooner than later. for many other reasons. Code well, hope it works out.

Comment: I found the official answer from Microsoft that in 2008 Management Studio you cannot setup backup of single objects. Although I am going to go with a different solution, your answer, workabyte, is the most realistic. Thank you.