# wpf - localdb backup

Tags: c#, wpf, localdb

I have created a WPF application using LocalDB, which is installed using ClickOnce. The application should allow the user to take the DB backup from one system and restore the same on other systems so as to be able to continue working with the same data. I cannot use a common shared database as the application needs to be used offline.
I plan to use the queries specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966891/wpf-how-to-backup-restore-localdb-programmatically-clickonce).

I'm using the following connection string to connect to LocalDB:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mscdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Since I do not know the `DataDirectory` in advance, at the time of backup, I'm using `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory` to obtain the path where the database is physically located on the user's system. This returns the following path in the user's directory (which I think will vary with every installation): `AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\OH3O4271.782\Q6DOAYQX.3CH\msc_..tion_3e1c52eacced2c3c_0001.0000_f97f25ea480d209d\Data`

I am using the following code to take the DB backup.

```
internal static void BackupDB(out string errorMessage)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                string dataDirectory = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory;
                string backupQuery = @"BACKUP DATABASE ""{0}"" TO DISK = N'{1}'";
                backupQuery = string.Format(backupQuery, dataDirectory  + "\\mscdb.mdf", "D:\\backup.bak");
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(backupQuery, conn);
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                errorMessage = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

1. When I run this code, it throws an exception with the message `The identifier that starts with {data directory path} is too long. Maximum length is 128.` How can I fix this issue? Since ClickOnce installs the application in the user's Apps cache, the path will always be a long one.
2. The `DataDirectory` contains 2 files, a primary data file and a transaction log file. Do I need to backup the log file as well to successfully restore the database on other systems? The code for restoring the database [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966891/wpf-how-to-backup-restore-localdb-programmatically-clickonce) does not mention the log file.
3. Since I'm unable to proceed, I'm not even sure if this approach will work correctly for backing up and restoring LocalDB. Is this okay? Or is there a better way of achieving my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you cannot reference the path of the mdf in order to make a backup. Instead, you have to use your database name or id.
It will generate a single .bak file, so you don't need to worry about ldf and mdf files.

Example:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MY_DATABASE TO DISK=N'C:\my_database.bak';
```

However, when you restore your database you might want to relocate the paths of the mdf and ldf files.

Example:

```
RESTORE database MY_DATABASE_2 FROM DISK=N'C:\my_database.bak'
WITH 
MOVE N'{mdf_name}' TO N'{mdf_new_path}', 
MOVE N'{ldf_name}' TO N'{ldf_new_path}';
```

Here you have the full syntax of the BACKUP and RESTORE commands:

- BACKUP: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx
- RESTORE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx

Comment: I had tried using just the database name, I'd gotten an error that database could not be found. Have you tried the above code using localdb?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that code within a LocalDB instance. Execute this `Select * from Sys.Databases` to check your current existing databases.